# Jasper Ireport Alternate row colors with custom style

Tags: jasper-reports

I've add a conditionnal style to my report for alternate row style like this :

```
<style name="tab_page_4">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 1]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#E7ECF4"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
</style>

<reportElement key="textField" style="tab_page_4" mode="Opaque" x="11" y="5" width="94" height="15" forecolor="#00597C" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4ea6f9a0-d1c8-42f0-8ae4-7c9780fcfe3d"/>
```

When i generate my report, the custom style doesnt work.

What i've forgot ?

Comment: Try to change textField definition: `<reportElement key="textField" style="tab_page_4"  x="11" y="5" width="94" height="15" uuid="4ea6f9a0-d1c8-42f0-8ae4-7c9780fcfe3d"/>`

Comment: i've delete Opaque property, no change

Comment: What about removing colors? And you forgot to add `mode="Opaque"` to style

Comment: I've add a Opaque in a custom style and it work's very fine, thanks Alex K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using conditional styles, it is important to remove all style data in the element. This means that in this case the elements `mode`, `forecolor` and `backcolor` should be removed so that the style is used.

It is possible to set e.g. the `forecolor` on an element when using a conditional to set the forecolor explicitly for this element. But usually all coloring will happen with the conditional style.

**EDIT**

As Alex K pointed out, make sure the conditional style also sets `mode="Opaque"`:

```
<style name="tab_page_4" mode="Opaque">
    ....
</style>
```

Or if using conditional styles:

```
<conditionalStyle>
    <conditionExpression>...</conditionExpression>
    <style mode="Opaque" .../>
</conditionalStyle>
```

Comment: I've delete mode, forecolor and backcolor from element, the odd lines doesnt appear

Answer (score 1):

I resolve a bug by following the notes of @Alex K and @Tobi6

The code of my ireport is now like this :

```
<style name="tab_page_4">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 1]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#00597C" backcolor="#E7ECF4"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#00597C" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
```

And in my element :

```
<reportElement key="textField" style="tab_page_4" x="0" y="0" width="105" height="25" uuid="4ea6f9a0-d1c8-42f0-8ae4-7c9780fcfe3d"/>
```